# Linux Centos 6.6: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, mysql.sock

I am trying to connect with mysql 5.6 in Linux with:

```
[C003@C-003 mysql]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I am getting above error. I found lot of hints but not one working for me and I cant take so much risks for Live server.

some commands output as follow:

```
[C003@C-003 mysql]$ service mysql status
ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found

[C003@C-003 mysql]$ ps -ef|grep mysql
root      1419     1  0 Apr28 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/SI-CloudDB-003.pid
mysql     1731  1419  6 Apr28 ?        20:58:36 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/SI-CloudDB-003.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/SI-CloudDB-003.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3310
501      30843 28738  0 11:41 pts/2    00:00:00 grep mysql
```

Comment: Sounds like it belongs to serverfault.com instead of stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: Its belong with MySQL database service on Linux server. Linux server is running fine but db configurations are creating problem.

Comment: It still is not about programming, so it is off Topic. :)

Comment: I try a lot to connect with db server but fail and my backups are not running due to this.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurred if you have changed default datadir location..
You need to create softlink in this case.. follow the below steps:

Step1: Stop DB service

## service mysqld stop

Step2: create softlink on default location i.e. /var/lib pointing to new DB data location.

## ln -s /Data/lib/mysql mysql

Step3: restart mysqld service

## service mysqld restart

You should able to connect the mysql db...

Answer (score 0):

Check that /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists and what ownership/permissions does the file have

Comment: this file not exist at /var/lib/MySQL  and even file not available in the whole system.

Comment: lowercase path names

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. I create file at /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock and set ownership to MySQL user and group. When try to shutdown the service I got error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock'". I kill the mysql background process through kill -9 process_id and then start the mysql service. Now its working fine.